# unable to generate html file in dist folder?

Tags: angular, npm, .net-core

I am developing web application in Angular5. I am trying to run my project using npm as `npm run dev-build`. When I do this dist folder creates under wwwroot. But this does not have any html file to run. It contains only font files, vendor.js, vendor.css and other files also. I am using VS2017 with .NET Core. My projects contain some C# core components like startup.cs which is used to load initial configurations.

I want to know if the project contains CS files then am I able to run my project as `npm run dev-build`? If yes, then where can I see my html page or how to run the project? Can someone help me out to make the confusions clear?

Comment: does generated artefacts contains `index.html`?

Comment: No it does not conatin index.html